# How does __setattr__ work with class attributes?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand exactly how `__setattr__` works with class attributes. This question came about when I attempted to override `__setattr__` to prevent attributes from being written to in a simple class.

My first attempt used instance level attributes as follows:

```
class SampleClass(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.PublicAttribute1 = "attribute"

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        raise Exception("Attribute is Read-Only")
```

I had originally thought that only external attempts to set the attribute would throw an error, but even the statement inside the `__init__` caused the exception to be thrown.

Later I ended up finding another way to do this, while attempting to solve a different problem. What I ended up with was:

```
class SampleClass(object):
    PublicAttribute1 = "attribute"

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        raise Exception("Attribute is Read-Only")
```

I expected to get the same result, but to my surpirse I was able to set the class attribute while preventing changes from being made after the initial declaration.

I don't understand why this works though. I know it has to do with class vs. instance variables. My theory is that using `__setattr__` on a class variable will create an instance variable of the same name, since I believe I think I have seen this behavior before, but I am not sure.

Can anyone explain exactly what is happening here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`__setattr__()` applies only to instances of the class. In your second example, when you define `PublicAttribute1`, you are defining it on the class; there's no instance, so `__setattr__()` is not called.

N.B. In Python, things you access using the `.` notation are called attributes, not variables. (In other languages they might be called "member variables" or similar.)

You're correct that the class attribute will be shadowed if you set an attribute of the same name on an instance.  For example:

```
class C(object):
    attr = 42

 c = C()
 print(c.attr)     # 42
 c.attr = 13
 print(c.attr)     # 13
 print(C.attr)     # 42
```

Python resolves attribute access by first looking on the instance, and if there's no attribute of that name on the instance, it looks on the instance's class, then that class's parent(s), and so on until it gets to `object`, the root object of the Python class hierarchy.

So in the example above, we define `attr` on the class.  Thus, when we access `c.attr` (the instance attribute), we get 42, the value of the attribute on the class, because there's no such attribute on the instance. When we set the attribute of the instance, then print `c.attr` again, we get the value we just set, because there is now an attribute by that name on the instance. But the value `42` still exists as the attribute of the class, `C.attr`, as we see by the third `print`.

The statement to set the instance attribute in your `__init__()` method is handled by Python like any code to set an attribute on an object. Python does not care whether the code is "inside" or "outside" the class. So, you may wonder, how can you bypass the "protection" of `__setattr__()` when initializing the object? Simple: you call the `__setattr__()` method of a class that doesn't have that protection, usually your parent class's method, and pass it your instance.

So instead of writing:

```
self.PublicAttribute1 = "attribute"
```

You have to write:

```
 object.__setattr__(self, "PublicAttribute1", "attribute")
```

Since attributes are stored in the instance's attribute dictionary, named `__dict__`, you can also get around your `__setattr__` by writing directly to that:

```
 self.__dict__["PublicAttribute1"] = "attribute"
```

Either syntax is ugly and verbose, but the relative ease with which you can subvert the protection you're trying to add (after all, if you can do that, so can anyone else) might lead you to the conclusion that Python doesn't have very good support for protected attributes. In fact it doesn't, and this is by design. "We're all consenting adults here." You should not think in terms of public or private attributes with Python. All attributes are public. There is a *convention* of naming "private" attributes with a single leading underscore; this warns whoever is using your object that they're messing with an implementation detail of some sort, but they can still do it if they need to and are willing to accept the risks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This explanation was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

The `__setattr__` method defined in a class is only called for attribute assignments on *instances* of the class. It is not called for class variables, since they're not being assigned on an instance of the class with the method.

Of course, classes are instances too. They're instances of `type` (or a custom metaclass, usually a subclass of `type`). So if you want to prevent class variable creation, you need to create a metaclass with a `__setattr__` method.

But that's not really what you need to make your class do what you want. To just get a read-only attribute that can only be written once (in the `__init__` method), you can probably get by with some simpler logic. One approach is to set another attribute at the end of the `__init__` method, which tells `__setattr__` to lock down assignments after it is set:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self._initialized = True

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if self.__dict__.get('_initialized'):
            raise Exception("Attribute is Read-Only")
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

Another option would be to use `property` descriptors for the read-only attributes and store the real values in "private" variables that can be assigned to normally. You'd not use `__setattr__` in this version:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

foo = Foo(3, 5)
foo.a = 7 # causes "AttributeError: can't set attribute"
```

Comment: I had actually tried something very similar to your first suggestion, however I did know about the self.__dict__get('initialized') and I ended up throwing the error when I attempted to set my Boolean value. The other reason I had moved away from these types of approaches is that I wanted to use the attribute externally in places where I did not always have an instance of the class. That may not be good python programming practice though. I am still relatively new to the language so I am not sure.

Answer (score 5):

`__setattr__` is only invoked on *instances* of a class and not the actual class itself. However, the class is still an object, so when setting the attribute of the class the `__setattr__` of the class of the class is invoked.

To change how attributes are set on classes you need to look into meta-classes. Metaclasses are overkill for almost any application, and can get confusing very easily. And trying to make a user-defined class/object read-only is normally a bad idea. That said, here is a simple example.

```
>>> class SampleMetaclass(type): # type as parent, not object
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...         raise AttributeError("Class is read-only")
... 
>>> class SampleClass(metaclass=SampleMetaclass):
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...         raise AttributeError("Instance is read-only")
... 
>>> SampleClass.attr = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __setattr__
AttributeError: Class is read-only
>>> s = SampleClass()
>>> s.attr = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __setattr__
AttributeError: Instance is read-only
```

Comment: `__setattr__` of the metaclass is only invoked when binding an attribute to an instance of the metaclass (the class), not when you're setting up a class variable as in the OP's case

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Right you are. But that's a bit more tricky as Python needs to be able to set a few class attributes itself. Doable though.

Comment: You can catch class attributes in the `__new__` of the metaclass. Might be sufficient to check attributes that pass `not attr.startswith('__')`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Good luck defining functions on your class then. And a class is kind of point less if it can't have functions.

Comment: I know, I know it's complicated, but checking `not callable(attr)` fixes that.

Answer (score 2):

The below can be found in the python documentation

> Attribute assignments and deletions update the instance’s dictionary, never a class’s dictionary. If the class has a __setattr__() or __delattr__() method, this is called instead of updating the instance dictionary directly.

As you can clearly see the *__setattr__()* changes the instances dictionary when it is called. So whenever you try to assign a **self.instance** it raises your exception  **Exception("Attribute is Read-Only")**.
Whereas that's not the case with setting a class's attribute so no  exception is raised.

Comment: Thank you. That explains why the second example works, but I still don't see why, in the second case, if I attempt to set the class variable it throws the error. If I call foo.PublicAttribute1 = "newattribute" on a n instance of the class, am I not setting the class variable? Wouldn't this bypass the \_\_setattr\_\_() according to the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

`__setattr__()` is called whenever a value is assigned to any of the class's property. Even if the property is initialized in the `__init__()`, it will make call to `__setattr__()`. Below is the example to illustrate that:

```
>>> class X(object):
...     def __init__(self, a, b):
...         self.a = a
...         self.b = b
...     def __setattr__(self, k, v):
...         print 'Set Attr: {} -> {}'.format(k, v)
...
>>> x = X(1, 3)       # <-- __setattr__() called by __init__() 
Set Attr: a -> 1
Set Attr: b -> 3
>>> x.a = 9           # <-- __setattr__() called during external assignment
Set Attr: a -> 9
```