# Block setting of class attributes (__setattr__)

Tags: python, setattr

1. is there a simple way to prevent setting new class attrs?
2. while trying with the following snippet, shouldn't `setattr(Derived, "test1", 1)` call the `__setattr__` from `Base`?

```
class Base:
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        raise PermissionError('in base')
    
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        def _setattr_(inst, key, val):
            raise PermissionError('in derived')
        cls.__setattr__ = _setattr_
        
class Derived(Base):
    pass

setattr(Derived, "test1", 1)

Derived.__setattr__(Derived, "test2", 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
PermissionError: in derived

Base.__setattr__(Derived, "test3", 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
PermissionError: in base
```

**EDIT**:
this is a duplicate. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python).

The `__setattr__` method you define in a class only affects instances of that class (or instances of subclasses), but not subclasses or the class itself (this is true for most methods exlcuding stuff like `__new__` and `__init_subclass__`).

`setattr(cls, attr_name, value)` calls `cls.__class__.__setattr__(cls, attr_name, value)`, but `Derived.__class__ == type`, not `Base`

Answer (score 1):

After a better selection of keywords and another round of searches I found this problem solved [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39709070/14094460). I am keeping it here as others might have the same difficulty to find one or the other, hence increasing the chances of getting a match.
Also here's the solution to the prob (minimal working example):

```
class Meta(type):
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        raise PermissionError('in meta')

class Base(metaclass=Meta):
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        raise PermissionError('in base')

class Derived(Base):
    pass

setattr(Derived, "test1", 1)
.
.
.
PermissionError: in meta
```